# Given a square matrix $A$, find an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS = J_A$

Tags: linear-algebra

My matrix is

\begin{bmatrix}7&4\\-4&-1\end{bmatrix}

I found the characteristic polynomial to be $(t-3)^2$, so my eigenvalue is the repeated root of this polynomial $t = 3$.  I proceeded to find the corresponding eigenvector(s) by finding the nullspace of $A - 3I_2$, which ended up being $Span((-1, 1)^T)$.  Since this is a line, I know my Jordan canonical form for $A$ will be:

\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\0&3\end{bmatrix}

Then to find my other eigenvectors, I need to solve the following equation (given by the second column of $J_A$:

$v_1 + 3v_2 = Av_2$

We can let $v_1$ be $(-1, 1)^T$ from above, then we have:

$(-1, 1)^T + 3(a, b)^T = A(a, b)^T$

This gives me the system:

$-1 + 3a = 7a + 4b$ and $1 + 3b = -4a - b$

The system reduces to $0 = 0$ which makes no sense.

How do I find my other eigenvector?

Answer (score 2):

The other *eigenvector* is no eigenvector in the ordinary sense, it is a vector that resides in the *generalized eigenspace* which is $$\det({\bf A}-3{\bf I})^k=0, k>1$$If you calculate for example $k=2$ you get the 0 matrix. Therefore the generalized eigenspace for $\lambda = 3$ is all of ${\mathbb R}^2$ in our case.

You can either solve the matrix equation:
$$\bf AS = SJ$$

Where $\bf J$ is the Jordan matrix block you describe and $\bf A$ is the matrix and first column in $\bf S$ is the eigenvector.
Or we can try minimizing:
$$\|({\bf A}-3{\bf I}){\bf v} - [-1,1]^T\|_2^2$$

Now maybe it gets easier to solve.

Comment: hmm, I tried using the first method and got the same two equations I had in my op.  Let me do it again to make sure,

Comment: Should my matrix $S$ be this?: \begin{bmatrix}-1&a\\1&b\end{bmatrix}

Comment: If I'm not too tired it should be the column $\begin{bmatrix}-1&a\\1&b\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: why doesn't method 1 work here?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the other Jordan basis vector you’re trying to compute is a *generalized* eigenvector, but that’s bit of terminology isn’t the crucial thing here. There’s no such thing as *the* (generalized) eigenvector, since any scalar multiple of it is also a (generalized) eigenvector of the same eigenvalue.

The fact that your system of equations “reduces to $0=0$” means that the two equations aren’t independent and have an infinite number of solutions. Solve one of the equations for $b$ and then choose a convenient value of $a$, and you’ll have your generalized eigenvector.

Comment: $−1+3a=7a+4b$, if we let $b=1$ then $a = -\frac{5}{4}$ and my other vector is $( -\frac{5}{4}, 1)^T$.